# Array List Help

Tags: java, reference, arraylist

I'm trying to add an object to an array list but having a bit of difficulty. I know my problem, but not how to fix it. Basically, the problem is that I'm assigning the references to the object in the array list x number of times. This is good, I want this. However, the reference is always changing to be the last-added thing?

Here's my code:

```
ID ids = new ID("1", "this is a string", "213", "example", "my", "name", "7939","1d", "1");
idarray.add(ids);

ids = new ID("2", "this too, is a string", "12314", "example2", "my", "name", "250","1234", "1");
idarray.add(ids);

ids = new ID("3", "Hey look! another string!", "10941", "examplar!", "my", "name", "1341","da34", "0");
idarray.add(ids);

ids = new ID("4", "the final example!", "109231091", "for example", "my", "name", "799","DF1234", "0");
idarray.add(ids);
```

The idea is that I'm trying to create a new "]ID" object containing all of that information, then store it in a "ids" arraylist to be access later. The problem is that I'm only storing the references, and when called it seems that EVERY stored reference is pointing to the last-in values?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not get what the problem is. Can you post the code which gives you undesired result?

Comment: What code you've posted seems to be correct. Consider posting some of the output that you're getting that indicates something is failing.

Comment: Your code looks correct. Can you post the code that shows that "every stored reference is pointing to the last-in values"?

Comment: Are the fields in your `ID` class static?  If you do something like `class ID { static String id;  ID(String theId, ...) { id = theId; } }` then each call to the `ID` constructor will clobber the work the previous call did.

Comment: Why are you storing the numbers in the ID constructor as Strings??

Comment: @Victor Sorokin , @glowcoder , @Cameron Skinner :

The code that I'm using to inspect it is:

`code: System.out.println(ids.get(ids.size()-1)); `

after every "add" statement to show that they have been added properly. Also, Later, I'm trying to: `code:
System.out.println(ids.get(ids.size()-2).getsubname()+"THIS SHOULD RETURN THE NAME OF THE THIRD-IN-LINE"); `

This will always return the 4th value. The "getsubname()" method simply returns all of the strings separated by a comma while I'm still testing exactly how to do this.

Comment: @Mike Samuel :

No, nothing is static. I made sure to check that first.

@Amir Afghani - 

It's for testing purposes, and because the object it is creating needs them to be strings for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

To access the specified object.

```
int index = 0;
ids = idarray.get(index);
```

That way you can retrieve the objects you already added.

You can't store all the references in a variable, for that you use arrays or collections, that's why is changing to the last value because you are assigning new reference each time you call:

```
ids = new ID("2", "this too, is a string", "12314", "example2", "my", "name", "250","1234", "1");
ids = new ID("3", "Hey look! another string!", "10941", "examplar!", "my", "name", "1341","da34", "0");
```

So now ids variable is pointing to the last reference you assigned.